# Is this a real quote or is it written for the movie?

Tags: dialogue, bharat-ane-nenu

In the movie *[Bharat Ane Nenu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharat_Ane_Nenu)*, there is a dialogue said the protagonist who plays a role of chief minister. While explaining self governance in the assembly, he says a dialogue. It is (own translation)

> A wise man said "Building a society which doesn't need a leader is the nature of a true leader." I strongly believe in that.

Is above quote or a similar variation of this a real quote or is it written for the movie and attributed to some wise man for the sake?

Answer (score 4):

## This sounds most like Lao-Tzu,

who often spoke about how the best leader is one that's invisible to it's people. That, they do such a good job of satisfying their peoples' needs, then, it's as if the people are doing it on their own.

> "A leader is best when people barely know he exists, when his work is done, his aim fulfilled, they will say: we did it ourselves." -- *Tao Te Ching*, Lao-Tzu